# *ngFor not looping correctly through items

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I cant seem to figure out whats wrong here..

my *ngFor isnt working

my html

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__seperator">This is some text</li>
    <li *ngFor="let feed of feeds" (click)="selectItem('.tick-' + feed.id)" class="item-{{feed.id}}"><img class="list__tick tick-{{feed.id}}" src="../../../assets/img/svg/icon-tick.svg">{{feed.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

my component.ts

```
export class FileComponent implements OnInit {
  feeds: [
     { id: 1, text: 'Example 1' },
     { id: 2, text: 'Example 2' },
     { id: 3, text: 'Example 3' },
     { id: 4, text: 'Example 4' }
  ];
```

I look at the rendered html where the list items should be there is.. `<!--bindings={}-->`

to me this should be working? what am I doing wrong?

any help would be appreciated and let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the array to the feeds as

```
  feeds = [
     { id: 1, text: 'Example 1' },
     { id: 2, text: 'Example 2'},
     { id: 3, text: 'Example 3'},
     { id: 4, text: 'Example 4'}
  ];
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-acycja?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**